# How to check the email and password field using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to check if a row with two values for two columns exists.  I tried the following code, but it only works for the first column, email, but not pass.  How do I check both columns in the `where` clause?

```
session.query(exists().where(User.email == '...' and User.pass == '...')).scalar()
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy filter objects are combined with the bitwise operators `&` and `|`, not the boolean `and` and `or`.

```
session.query((exists().where(User.email == '...') & (User.password == '...'))).scalar()
```

There are also [`and_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=and_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) and `or_` functions to combine multiple statements.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

sa.and_(User.email == '...', User.password == '...')
```